# Accessing a child inside a vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm completely new to Vuejs and have a problem I'm not able to solve.

Below is my HTML:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <template id="upload-button">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Uploaden" @click="uploadButtonClicked">
      Uploaden
    </button>
    <input ref="uploadTag" type="file" name="{{name}}" accept="{{mime}}"  />
  </template>  
  <upload-button url="http://www.google.com" method="post" name="pol" mime=".json"></upload-button>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
Vue.component('upload-button', {
  template: '#upload-button',
  props:{
    url: String,
    method: String,
    name: String,
    mime: String
  }, 
  methods:{
    uploadButtonClicked: function(){
        console.log(this.$refs);
        var uploadTag = this.$refs.uploadTag;
      alert(uploadTag);
    }
  },
});

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

The thing is that the `this.$refs` stays empty all the time. I read in the docs that it gets populated after the component is mounted.
When I click the button element, I suppose that the component is already mounted. Is that true?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking in your console? You'll quickly see that Vue has not rendered your page, because your template is not valid. You need to remove the dynamic attributes from your input, then move your component template out of the subtree under app. When Vue is able to generate the render function, your `$refs` work just fine.

Here are the markup changes [working in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdgnnwxd/)...

```
<div id="app" class="container">  
  <upload-button url="http://www.google.com" method="post" name="pol" mime=".json"></upload-button>
</div> 
<template id="upload-button">
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Uploaden" @click="uploadButtonClicked">
      Uploaden
    </button>
    <input ref="uploadTag" type="file" name="garbage" accept="application/json"  />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Alright that's a stupid mistake I made. I didn't receive a single message in my console. Strange.
 I've updated the fiddle so I can bind the dynamic properties to the input field -> https://jsfiddle.net/rdgnnwxd/1/

Comment: Not in Vue2 you can't? Please don't go back to Vue1. You need to stay with the curve ! Use v-bind to get dynamic attributes.

Comment: Just looking at your updated fiddle. At the moment your attributes aren't dynamic. You need `v-bind` (or `:`) in front of the name to make them so.